# How to launch a script that execute a check disk (chkdsk) without manual confirmation in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, automation

I have a supervision tool that can deploy scripts on customers end devices.
I'm trying to make two powershell scripts.
The first one is supposed to launch a "chkdsk *disk_name:* /f /r".
The second one is supposed to extract the result of the chkdsk after the reboot from the event viewer.

The second script is operational. My problem is with the first one.
I think that when I'm launching my job from my administration tool, the script is launched on the end device, but when you type "chkdsk *disk_name:* /f /r" on a command prompt, it asks if you want to do the chkdsk at the start of the machine because the disk is actually in use. I think that the letter "Y" that you have to type to confirm, is blocking the execution of the command (and my script by consequence).
I didn't find in the documentation of the command any method to launch it with a "default confirmation".
Do you have any idea of what I can do to automate this?

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.
Thank you all!

I tried to launch the script (it's in admin mode when my administration tool launch it's job) but the result was that my job was running indefinitely and at the restart of the machine, the check disk is not performed.

Comment: Try to avoid old fashion CLI commands in PowerShell where possible. Instead use the dedicated PowerShell cmdlets as in this case: [Repair-Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/storage/repair-volume)

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I saw that repair-volume existed but I couldn't really find an exact match of "chkdsk X /f /r". Can a "Repair-Volume -DriveLetter X -SpotFix" be a similar command ? Or maybe more "Repair-Volume -DriveLetter X -OfflineScanAndFix" ?

Comment: I guess that should do (almost) the same. The point is that is should at least make things easier to implement (invocation, elevating, capturing results, etc.).

Comment: I just implemented this solution with Repair-Volume and it works well. Thanks for your help!